# Z-index in html2pdf

Tags: html, css, z-index, html2pdf

I am trying to build an invoice template with http://www.simpleinvoices.org which has implemented **html2pdf**.

I have read the documentation and at http://www.tufat.com/docs/html2ps/compatibility.css.2.1.html I have found that the **z-index** compatibility is "partial, Supported for absolute-positioned boxes only; only numeric values are supported".

My layout needs a watermark image (it´s a jpg), but with a higher resolution than 72ppp, that´s why I´m trying to wrap the data tables into a container DIV and the watermark into another one, instead of using the background-image as usual (CSS2.1 doesn´t allow to customize the background image size).

**CSS**

```
#container{
    width:700px; 
    position: relative; /* changing to absolute doesn´t work either */
    display:block; 
    z-index:1 !important; 
    margin:15px auto; 
}

#watermark{
    width: 500px; /* image size */
    top:730px;
    left:253px;
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:-1 !important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">    
    <table>
    ...
    </table>
</div>

<div id="watermark">    
    <img src="...">
</div>
```

Why the table is shown above the watermark image in the HTML preview (the right behavior) and the opposite in the PDF (the table below the image, which is wrong)?

Any solution, please?

TIA

Comment: Remove `!important` and try?

Comment: Hi @Dream Eater, thanks for the reply, I have tried with and without `!important` and it doesn´t work.

Comment: @Pablo Can you create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) demo

Comment: Hi @user1479606, here is the link http://jsfiddle.net/sSAUJ, but remember the issue is within the generated PDF, not the HTML preview.

Comment: Same problem. z-index is not working while the generation of PDF.